# Difference between automatic programming and compiling

Tags: compiler-construction, antlr, cheetah

CheetahTemplate allows source code generation, how is this different from a compiler generated through something like ANTLR?

Comment: Usually it is more domain specific. Compilers generally convert one general representation to another one.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "general representation"?

Comment: The representation of the problem is general, not tied to a specific set of problems. Template generators generate one type of applications, not all. Compilers for general languages are usually geared towards a bigger, if not infinite, set of potential problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't.

By the way, "Automatic programming" is a buzzword that's been around since the earliest computers (in fact, the technology that evolved into programming languages and compilers as we now know them was called "automatic programming" in the 1950s) and doesn't say anything useful.